# State necessary and sufficient conditions for $A$ and $B$ to be independent

Tags: probability, measure-theory

> (a) Let $\mathbb P$ be the uniform measure on $[0,1]$. Define $A = (a,b)$ and $B = (c,d)$, with $a < c$. State necessary and sufficient conditions for $A$ and $B$ to be independent.
> (b) Find an example of an $\omega , \mathbb P,$ and sets $A,B,C$ such that $$\mathbb P(A\cap B\cap C)=\mathbb P(A)\:\mathbb P(B)\:\mathbb P(C)$$ Where $A,B,$ and $C$ are not independent

$(a)$

For any interval $I = [a,b] ( $or $I=(a,b))$ in the set $\mathbb {R}$ of real numbers, let $\mathbb P(I)=b-a$ denote its length. I need to show the independence,
$$\mathbb P(A\cap B)=\mathbb P(A)\:\mathbb P(B)$$ but A; B; C are not independent.

I divide the whole scenario into three case:

- **$(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are disjoint:** then

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathbb P(A)\:\mathbb P(B) & = (b-a)(d-c) \\
\mathbb P(A\cap B) & = 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}

$\mathbb P(A\cap B)=\mathbb P(A)\:\mathbb P(B)$ either $(b-a)=0\implies a=b$ or $(d-c)=0\implies c=d$

- $a<c<d<b$ then $\mathbb P(A\cap B)=\mathbb P(A)\:\mathbb P(B) \implies (d-c)=(b-a)(d-c)$ which mean $(a,b)=(0,1)$
- $a<c<b<d$ then $\mathbb P(A\cap B)=\mathbb P(A)\:\mathbb P(B)$ if $(b-c)=(b-a)(d-c)$. Then I could detect any conclusion about them.

For $(b)$ I couldn't manage an example.

But I think I am not getting what they asked for. Any solution or hint will be appreciated. Sorry for the question title, I haven't any nice title for those question in my head now.

Comment: I don't know if this is allowed, but if the interval notation $(t,t)$ is interpreted as the empty set, then $A,B$ independent would hold provided either $a=b$ or $c=d$ [or both].

Comment: For part (b) what is the meaning of $\omega$ in "Find an example of an $\omega, \mathbb {P}$...."?

Comment: maybe $\omega$ stands for Sample space @coffeemath. For $(b)$, actually, I have found an example for pairwise independence which does not imply independence: Let one roll of a fair $9$-sided die. Let $A$ be the event we roll a $1, 2$ or $3$; $B$ be
the event we roll a $3, 4,$ or $5$; $C$ be the event we roll a $5, 6,$ or $1$.  But couldn't manage for that case.

Comment: Your second case is when $(c,d) \subset (a,b)$ and so $\mathbb P(A\cap B) = \mathbb P(B)$ equals $\mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(B)$ iff $\mathbb P(A) = 1 \implies (a,b) = (0,1)$.

Comment: Yes, @DilipSarwate. I get some intuition for inclusion and disjoint case. But I was getting problem with $a<c<b<d$ case.

Answer (score 1):

For your 9-sided die example, maybe $\mathcal X=\omega$ is the set on which the measure is defined, $\omega=\{1,2,3,...,9\}$, and let the $\mathcal A=\sigma$-field be the power set, and let $\mu=\mathbb P$ be the measure $1/9 \cdot \# A$ where $A$ is any of the subsets in $\mathcal A$. Let the events $A=\{1,2,3\}$, $B=\{3,4,5\}$ and $C=\mathcal X=\omega$. $A\cap B\cap C=\{3\}$.

$$P(A\cap B\cap C)=1/9=1/3\cdot 1/3\cdot 1=P(A)P(B)P(C)$$

Comment: Nice (+1) @Stacker. I was missing to include the whole sample space.

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding part (a)**

For the disjoint case you can write:

$A$ and $B$ are independent if and only if $A=\emptyset$ or $B=\emptyset$.

Try to write precise mathematical statements for the two other cases. I don't think you can achieve anything particularly nice in the final case. What you have seems good enough.

**Regarding part (b)**

*Edited answer after clarification:*

Let $X \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ denote a random variable such that $$X \sim \text{Bernoulli}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg).$$ For instance this can model a fair coin toss. Consider now
$$
A=\{X=0\}, \quad B=\{X=1\} \quad\text{and} \quad C= \emptyset.
$$
Note that $A,B$ and $C$ are *not* pairwise independent (and thus *not* independent) as
$$
\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) = \mathbb{P}(\emptyset) = 0 \neq \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B).
$$
However
$$
\mathbb{P}(A\cap B\cap C) = \mathbb{P}(\emptyset) = 0 = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot 0   = \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)\mathbb{P}(C)
$$
as desired.

Comment: **a counter example to pairwise independence implies independence** I got that counterexample, and I share it in the comment as a reference which isn't the actual question. What I asked to find an example where $A,B$ and $C$ are not independence but satisfying $$\mathbb P(A\cap B\cap C)=\mathbb P(A)\: \mathbb P(B)\: \mathbb P(C)$$ @Jacobiman

Comment: I update the question body for $(b)$. Maybe the context is clear now. Could you update the answer, please. Otherwise, it was seeing misleading.

Comment: @falamiw I have updated the answer now, hope this was what you were looking for then.